# Redirecting with sending Datas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I tried following code: if the user's info to login is not correct redirect the user to the loin page again with the a message:

```
if (!$info_is_correct){
    $_SESSION['err_msg'] = 'your login info is not correct';
    return redirect('http://localhost:8000/user/login');
}
```

this is what I do in the login page(view) to echo the error msg:

```
    @isset($_SESSION['err_msg'])
        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" style="font-family:IRANSans;font-size:16px ;">
            <p>
                <strong>خطا !</strong>
                {{$_SESSION['err_msg']}}
                <?php unset($_SESSION['err_msg']) ?>

            </p>
        </div>
    @endisset
```

where is the problem? and What is the best way to send data to view with redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) method:

```
return redirect('http://localhost:8000/user/login')->with('err_msg', 'your login info is not correct');
```

And if a view:

```
@if (session('err_msg'))
    <div>{{ session('err_msg') }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. But a question Can I have the session('something') as variable $something ?

Comment: @Mahdi you can pass it to the view as a variable `$something = session('something')` but you don't need to do this because `session()` is a globally accessible helper.

Comment: My mean is use $err_msg instead session('err_msg') in blade template.  Means doing something before redirecting. Can I ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using laravel the validations can be done by making use of [validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#introduction) and simply return

`redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)`

and from the view you can have access to an `$errors` variable which will hold all the errors,

and you can loop through errors variable and print out the errors

from your login view

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this to send your error messages with use inputs

```
return redirect('http://localhost:8000/user/login')->with('err_msg', 'Your error message')->withInput();
```

Source : [Laravel Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects), [Laravel Validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

Note : You can also work with Error Messages [like this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#working-with-error-messages)

Comment: Thank you. But when I do this work and redirect to login page and show the error When I press f6 button in my keyboard to refresh the page the error is shown yet. after the second refresh error will be hided. How can I show err_msg once?

Comment: You need to show error message always (I mean after several refresh) ?

Comment: no just once.  the above code shows error twice means for 2 refreshes

Answer (score 0):

Set session value in laravel with `session` method, be sure to use because it is global and set session value for whole site.

Also **remove** `http://localhost:8000` to work this route in both development and production.

```
if (!$info_is_correct){
    session('err_msg', 'your login info is not correct');
    return redirect('/user/login');
}
```

And get value form session as [session('key')](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#retrieving-data)

```
{{session('err_msg')}}
```