# Redirecting with sending Datas and Show them in view just once?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I asked this question in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879238/redirecting-with-sending-datas-in-laravel)(Please see this link before reding this question), and answer was correct but when I show the error in view after redirecting when I refresh the page, error exists yet.
I wanna know how to show msg once in view ?

Comment: [Flash](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session) the message?

Comment: @kerbholz pleas give me complete answer with code. and have a kook to the linked question. Thanks

Comment: Need to do some research/testing on your own. The link I provided has a chapter "Flash the data" with a simple line of code on how to flash data, which basically does what you want: keep the error/status message for one request.

Comment: Thanks. I used Flash but it shows error 2 times. I tried many ways too.

Comment: Ok, here's what I usually do: I have a [partial](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1700001) that I include `@include('_partials.session')` in my layout. In my controllers I use `Session::flash('warning', '...');` to trigger a warning and then redirect. Take a look at some other projects on GitHub/GitLab to see how they do it. Hope this helps